# Magento 2 - Display Custom Attribute on Cart Page

Tags: magento2, attributes, cart

**InstallData.php**

```
    namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_point',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Product Point',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 3,
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'group' => 'Product Details',
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

The attribute can be seen inserted in the table `eav_attribute`. It can also be seen on listing page using below code.

**app\code\Namespace\Module\Block\Product**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($product->getData());exit;
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Ei_Productpoint::points.phtml')->toHtml();
        $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
        if ($renderer) {
            $renderer->setProduct($product);
            return $html.$renderer->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Product Attribute can be seen as below in listing page

[image]

When I printed cart data

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($product->getdata());
```

it does not show my custom attribute. How do I display my custom attribute on cart page ?

[image: How can i display my custom attribute on cart page.]

Comment: This can be useful : [override block class by product type](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111062/magento-2-override-block-class-by-product-type)

Comment: did u found the solution for this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183767/magento-2-display-attribute-on-cart-page/183879#183879