# Magento 2 - Display Attribute on Cart Page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I need to display a few attributes in the cart page.
How can i accomplish that?
[image]

Comment: You Have to create attribute and assign to that product @Athbi

Comment: Look at these below link for clarity @Athbi

Comment: Hi @Athbi Please use the below code and get back with your comments thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer so that it will useful for the other developers thanks

Comment: Please comment me I u need assistance thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

*Assuming you have a module already created*

> Step 1: Create an attribute and assign to product Ex: discount_price 
>   (your product attribute). Call the same from your custom module as shown below:

**app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/catalog_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="discount_price"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Go to below path: 
>   **app/design/frontend/[themepackage]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

Use like this `<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('discount_price');?>`

> Step 3: Clear cache and page cache and go to frontend & check the
>   same.

Comment: Where exactly do I place the catalog_attributes.xml do I need to create a module?

Comment: In your custom module. If not plz create. Thanks

Comment: i am able to get value but it in integer that is option how can i get label or text value here ?