# How to show catalog attribute in cross-sell in shopping cart which overridden by an Extension module

Tags: cart, magento2.3, cross-sells

Magento 2.3

I have an extension's file that overrides my theme's file, which in turn overrides Magento core file.

the extension's file

```
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

My theme's file

```
app/design/frontend/MyThemeName/modulename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

Following advice from

[Magento 2 - Display Attribute on Cart Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183767/magento-2-display-attribute-on-cart-page)

does not work, I added the file `catalog_attributes.xml` in the extension module folder and modify the extension's `items.phtml`, but the page returns error

```
PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in 
/home/myusername/public_html/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

Comment: Have you added cross-sells products in which  product added in cart?

Comment: @Vijay-CyberLocker I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my other post, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/278940/80197

Following a few googled answers (as shown in original question) confused me in the universe of god.

I found out how to achieve this. It's as just simple as

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getData("short_description") ?>
```

`getShortDescription()` will work as well for above

For selected size of a product, instead of all the options of the size by using `getProductDetailsHtml()`,

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getAttributeText("size_owth") ?>
```

My wholeheartedly opinion:

PHPStorm does not show auto-completion for `getShortDescription()` and `getAttributeText()`, what a joke, even with the plugin for Magento too. And go to declaration (or goto definition) don't work these two methods as well.

Magento documentation sucks, wasting my time. It's like calling to you to read and try the classes one by one in the Magento Core, and one by one following the route of the models to retrieve the classes.